# Typescript higher order component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am running into a problem typing the following HOC. I've simplified it, but the use-case is modifying the classes on a wrapped component based on a new prop.

```
import React, { ComponentType } from 'react';

interface Classable {
  className?: string;
}

interface Fooable {
  foo: string;
}

function fooTheClass(foo: string, className?: string): string {
  // this is a simplified example..
  return className ? `$(className) ${foo}` : foo;
}

// HOC to modify className based on a new prop.
const withFoo = <P extends Classable>(Component: ComponentType<P>): ComponentType<P & Fooable> => {
  const newComponent = ({ foo, className, ...rest }: P & Fooable) => {
    return <Component className={fooTheClass(foo, className)} {...rest} />;
  };
  return newComponent;
};
```

This causes the following error:

> Type '{ className: string; } & Pick>' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes
>   & P & { children?: ReactNode; }'.   Type '{ className: string; } &
>   Pick>' is not
>   assignable to type 'P'. [2322]

I can eliminate the error if I don't destructure:

```
const withFoo1 = <P extends Classable>(Component: ComponentType<P>): ComponentType<P & Fooable> => {
  const newComponent = (props: P & Fooable) => {
    const { ...rest } = props;
    rest.className = fooTheClass(rest.foo, rest.className);
    delete rest.foo;
    return <Component {...rest } />;
  };
  return newComponent;
};
```

or with an explicit cast:

```
const withFoo2 = <P extends Classable>(Component: ComponentType<P>): ComponentType<P & Fooable> => {
  const newComponent = ({ foo, className, ...rest }: P & Fooable) => {
    return <Component className={fooTheClass(foo, className)} {...(rest as unknown as P)} />;
  };
  return newComponent;
};
```

(note that just:

```
return <Component className={fooTheClass(foo, className)} {...(rest as P)} />;
```

won't work).

These both seem like inelegant workarounds.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is using the predefined `React.FC` type instead of typing props directly:

```js
const withFoo = <P extends Classable>(
  Component: ComponentType<P>
): ComponentType<P & Fooable> => {
  const newComponent: React.FC<P & Fooable> = ({ foo, className, ...rest }) => {
    return <Component className={fooTheClass(foo, className)} {...rest as P} />;
  };
  return newComponent;
};
```